# Stylesheets, widgets hidden and sizes in Qt

Tags: qt, resize, qt4, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

There is a big problem with stylesheets.

If you set the sizes through the style sheet by setting max and min values the same (fixed size) or whatever, and then you try to fetch them using size() on the widget, **if the widget has never been shown the sizes you get are weird.**

But you can't fetch them from the stylesheet neither, so you have to **show all widgets before** resizing or fetching the positions.

In my case, i start with a window. But the widgets under this window will appear later, and **they have to be positioned in the correct positions before appearing**. i have floating widgets, they are not integrated as children of a QMainWindow, so i move them by hand, and position them... but how can i do it, if i don't know how they are?

*Do you know any other way to fetch the sizes stored in the stylesheet?.*

Comment: I guess it's not a big problem if the solution is a single method call that takes no arguments :) It *may be* a problem with the documentation, or PEBKAC, but not with stylesheets :)

Comment: Stylesheets documentation is for sure a very poor source of information. For me it has been sometimes a nightmare to guess these things. About that function call, i never saw it written ... anywhere... So i have to read the docs, never seen it! Let me check.

Comment: What exact platform is this (OS, compiler), and what exact version of Qt, and what options were given to `configure`? I really have trouble reproducing it.

Comment: Windows 64Bit, Visual Studio 2008 (which compiler? O_o). Qt4.7.

Comment: Right now your question is a candidate to be closed because either it can't be reproduced, or you didn't provide enough details (as in a self-contained minimal test case that shows it not working). There is really no way for anyone here to help you if there's no code to be seen.

Comment: Sure there's a way to fetch the stylesheet sizes, you either parse the stylesheet yourself, or use private Qt headers to access the stylesheet internals. But this is completely unnecessary and merely a workaround to whatever bug you have in your code.

Comment: `size()` will always be invalid before showing widget. Did you check if QWidget properties like `sizeHint`, `minimumSize`, `maximumSize` or `minimumSizeHint` return proper values for you?

Answer (score 7):

There are three solutions I know of, so far:

1. Polish the widget: call `widget->ensurePolished()`.
2. Polish the widget through the style: call `qApp->style()->polish(widget)`.
3. Send the events posted to the widget: `QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(widget, 0)` on the widgets before it's shown. With Qt 5, you don't need the second argument as it now has a default value of 0.

Another solution to your problem would be simply not writing any synchronous code at all. To lay out a top-level widget when it's first shown:

1. Install an event filter on the widget.
2. When the show event arrives on the widget:

   1. Uninstall the event filter from the widget.
   2. Deliver all of the window's events until none are left:

      ```
      while (widget->d_ptr->postedEvents)
        QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(widget, 0);
      ```

      You're now guaranteed  that the widget is visible and has the correct size.
   3. Use the widget's geometry and move it. If you need information from all the widgets to make that decision, store it in some data structure and process it only when all the widgets are there.

If you wish to prevent temporary visibility of widgets in wrong positions, you may wish to act on the resize event instead. The layout and styling system will resize the top-level widget suitably to fit its contents. You should uninstall the event filter and process the most recent geometry only when there are no more events to be delivered for that object upon return from the call to `sendPostedEvents`.

The following demonstrates the forced polishing approach, and works under both Qt 4.8.5 and 5.2.0. I've tested it on both 64 bit build on OS X, and a 32 bit build on Windows.

Note that neither `l1` nor `l2` is shown, yet they both report a correct size. `l3` is shown, but when queried before being shown, it reports the wrong size.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QStyle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString style("QLabel { min-height:100px; max-height:100px; min-width: 300px; max-width:300px }");
    a.setStyleSheet(style);
    QLabel l1, l2, l3;
    l1.ensurePolished(); // equivalent first/second methods
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(&l2, 0); // third method
    l3.setText(QString("l1: %1 x %2 l2: %3 x %4 l3: %5 x %6")
               .arg(l1.width()).arg(l1.height())
               .arg(l2.width()).arg(l2.height())
               .arg(l3.width()).arg(l3.height()));
    l3.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    l3.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.I didn't know about this function.But doesn't work for me. The stylesheet is assigned before creating the UI. Then after creating the hidden widget, i output the size( it is huge). Then i use that function. The size stays the same. Then after showing the widget, it gets smaller as the stylesheet told it.
Do not working for me.

Comment: In fact, as the docs say: "QWidget calls this function after it has been fully constructed but before it is shown the very first time". So, it is BY DEFAULT called.

Comment: @darkgaze You misunderstand what the docs say. There are two times where Qt can do significant things with a widget in this case: at construction, and at the time you call `show()`. It's single-threaded code, and won't do things for you when you call `size()`! So, the function can only be called when you call `show()`, but *before it has been made visible yet*. `show()` does a bunch of things before the widget is made visible. The docs really mean this: we'll call it when you call `show()`, but before the electrons hit the phosphor on the screen :)

Comment: Yeah!. But is there an answer implicit there?. I should not use that function there, it does nothing, and when i do "show()", it appears, but there is no way to insert between those two a reposition function.

Comment: I executed it and it worked. But my project has nearly 100 classes. Difficult to find out what could it be. I use a stylesheet loaded at the beginning. In what i did, using that doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @darkgaze Well, I can't really do your debugging for you. Problem solving in software development requires to narrow it down to the smallest reproducible case. It should be easy for you to copy the project and start throwing irrelevant things out. It's supposed to work, so your problem is not here, it's somewhere else in code that likely has got nothing to do with stylesheets etc.

Comment: Yeah. That´s probably some hidden feature over there... Let me check that new piece of code! Thanks.

Comment: For example, using setObjectName() does not work on runtime. But using:  style()->polish(object)  works for me at runtime!. But not ensurePolished... Still checking that.

Comment: About the new method sendPostedEvents, of the widgets i created, it doesn't work... Note that my panels (floating widgets) are not children of the main window. I move them by hand. Could that be the reason? But the styles work, anyways.

Comment: @darkgaze: I don't understand what you mean by `setObjectName()` does not work on runtime. If you seriously say that calling that method doesn't change the name of the object, then you're facing serious memory corruption and nothing is expected to work correctly. It doesn't make any sense for the widgets to be children of anything, since the example code here only tests top-level widgets. I've never claimed it would work on child widgets. It may or may not work on them.

Comment: setObjectName works on code, but when you use stylesheets and you change the object name on runtime, the style does not change. I have to call "style()->polish(object)" to make it know what is happening. Do you think it is a problem with my code??

Comment: @darkgaze Yes. Nothing in the documentation claims that `setStyleSheet` has immediate effects. All that is guaranteed is that *afterwards*, when the event loop has drained the event queue, the effects of setting the style will take effect and will be visible. In Qt, updating the display is done asynchronously from the event loop. Since you cannot paint on demand, it doesn't make any sense for the styling mechanism to pretend that you can. The visual and non-visual effects of the style are set at the same point, asynchronously as the relevant events are drained from the queue.

Comment: Yeah, i understand. But changing style with setObjectName never updates... MM. I think this is too big to analyse, que whole problem. The sizes not returned correctly.... If i had time to understand all of these, my project is so big i can´t stop to investigate, i´m afraid. If you think it is some problem in my code, and not a general issue with Qt, then i leave this question here and wait for some spare time to investigate... Thanks!

Comment: The asynchonous use of eventFilter is genious!